# How to properly position a div while floating it right in respect to another div

Tags: css, html

My apologies if the question is not worded correctly. Not sure how to ask it. Wrote it out many different ways.

To better understand here is a image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Iat.jpg

I am floating a div to the left inside a container div and a div to the right. (floating a title div to the left as well named resources) the right floating div is a map. I would like to move it up 20 or 30pxs so that it is only 5 pxs from the top of the container div like the title div is to the left of it. I would like to do this while still floating the left div (the links) to the left side of the map div. Not below it. That may have been confusing to read but the image illustrates the simplicity of it. How do I slide the map div up so that it is only 5pxs from the top border of the container div like the title div is to the left

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code have you tried?  A negative margin might be a quick and easy fix.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that. That worked exactly as I needed it to. Thanks. Want to answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a negative margin on the map `div`.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 2):

- Create TWO containing DIVS
- Give them both a CSS "display" value of `inline-block`
- Enjoy.

> ```
> <div id='l' style="display:inline-block">
>      <h2>A Header</h2>
>      <p>This is a description...etcetera</p>
> </div>
> <div id='r' style="display:inline-block">
>      <div id='theMap'></div>
> </div>
> ```

For some reason though it only seems to work if I float them both to the left instead.
http://jsfiddle.net/hX5eB/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer also. I upvoted it too. It also works.